# How can i explicitly hint Valgrind about intentially non freed memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a good number of memory allocations i just want to let die with the process because of complicated synchronisation issues and other convenience.

I don't want to write a suppression file.

Is there some C code that i can signal this to avoid false positives (not really false but unwanted). I know valgrind has an API but failed to find that.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a suppression file will probably be the easiest way. Valgrind can generate the suppressions for you with `--gen-supressions=all`.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to quiet valgrind would be store your "leaked" pointers in a process-lifetimed data structure so that valgrind reports them as "still reachable" rather than "definitely leaked".  For example, in the code below, I call `IgnoreThisLeak(leakMe)` to keep valgrind from complaining that I never free my 100-byte allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
   struct Node * _nextNode;
   void * _leakPtr;
};

static void IgnoreThisLeak(void * leakPtr)
{
   static struct Node * _tail = NULL;

   struct Node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   n->_nextNode = _tail;
   n->_leakPtr  = leakPtr;
   _tail = n;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int * leakMe = malloc(100);

    IgnoreThisLeak(leakMe);
    printf("leakMe=%p\n", leakMe);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that I used a linked-list as my data structure only because the question mentioned C and that was the easiest way to implement a variable-length list in C.  For C++ you could just `push_back(leakMe)` to a `std::vector<void *>` or whatever.

Comment: You could also use circular pointers..